# Parallelize commandblock that takes arguments that are filenames and include an if statement?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I have a script here that I parallelized somewhat to access files from two different directories for various processes. However, I made it so that the files are placed in a new directory but because I have so many files (and a time limit to execute each script) where would I add the if statement for my script so that it doesn't re-analyze the same set of files?

```
#!/bin/bash
#SLURM CODE BlOCK

# Assemble reads if not already done
path=$PWD
for files in $path/Test_Folder/refs/*.fa
do
    REF=$(basename $files)
    if [ -e $path//${REF%%.fa}_dir ]  #check if directory exists
    then
        echo "Directory exists, skipping!"
    else
        parallel -j 1 "bwa mem -B 2 -M -t 2 $files {1} \
        > {1/.}_${REF%%.fa}.sam\
        && echo 'Running bwa mem for {2} using $REF'\
        & mkdir -p ${REF%%.fa}_dir \
        & mv {1/.}_${REF%%.fa}.sam ${REF%%.fa}_dir"\
        :::: < (ls Test_Folder/.fastq)
     fi
done
```

But my error is that for some reason it can't find the index files which are all in the same folder as $REF - this wasn't an issue but now it just fails at locating them. I think because I no longer tell it to access that folder in the parallel loop as I call $REF? Really strange.

EDIT: I fixed the error I just had a typo in my script. As of right it SEEMS to be doing what I want but I can only verify this in a day or two after testing actual large files - it works with tiny files.

Comment: What is a 'REF file' ? can you post example ?

Comment: Sorry I read the question wrong, a REF file is a fasta file with one sequence that the FASTQ files will be assembled against. Normally you use one REF file to assemble a bunch of FASTQ files depending on how many samples there are. In my case because of various tests I am doing I have several REF files that I want to loop through, each that will be used as a reference for my several FASTQ files to be assembled against. Maybe I should loop through just FASTQ and then somehow call the script each time for a different REF file but I don't think that will speed anything up?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with those files. You might want to post an example of expected behavior, given small set of input files.

Comment: The files are massive and honestly what the files look like isn't my problem here, I just wanted to properly access files from 2 different directories. I have updated my script as I had somewhat figured it out but now I just have to add an if statement somewhere so that when I rerun my script, it isn't going over the same files all over again.

Comment: `I don't want it to redo everything` - this really sounds like a `make` script. A utility to [compile files](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overview). Basically you are "compiling" `{1}` and `{2}` using `bwa` what results in `{2/.}_{1/.}.sam`. Do you want to run the command foreach `*.fa` file and foreach `*.fastq` file? So for example, for 3 fa files and 5 fastq files you want to run 15 commands, right?

Comment: What's a make script?

Comment: Each .fa file will be used once for each .fastq, so yes essentially I would end up with 15 output files so I am executing bwa mem 15 times. It works with my script as is but because of time limits or random kills, if I rerun the script it will redo it all instead of continuing with the files it hasn't executed for yet. So I'm trying to see how to either input parallel into an if statement. I have no idea how to compile scripts and that is nothing something I can learn at the moment - just gotta work with what I understand.

Comment: I almost had it to work but instead of skipping the files it already processed, it says it does skip but still processes them anyway - I've updated my script to reflect what I've tried.

Comment: Oh nevermind I got it to work I had a typo. As of right now it seems to be doign what I want but I have to run it for a while to be sure - will update this post once that is done (about a day or two).